# Weak formulation with non homogeneous Dirichlet

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I have to find the Weak formulation oh this problem:

$$ \left\{ \begin{gathered}
  u'' = f{\text{ on  }}  \Omega =\left] {0,1} \right[ \hfill \\
  u(0) = \alpha  \hfill \\
  u(1) = \beta  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.$$

Which space should I take?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you only have Dirichlet boundary conditions, you can take the space
$$V=\{v \in H^1(0,1) \mid v(0)=0=v(1)\}$$

You have to use a "lift" function $R$: define $\tilde u = u - R$ so that $\tilde u(0)=0, \tilde u(1)=0$ i.e. $\tilde u \in V$.

You can take $R(\cdot)$ to be an affine map, for instance $R(x)=(\beta - \alpha)x + \alpha$

Your weak formulation will look like this:

> $u=\tilde u + R$, and $a(\tilde u, v) := \int_0^1 -\tilde u'v' = \int_0^1 (f \cdot v + R' \cdot v') =: \tilde F(v)$ for all $v\in V$.